# How to pass cookies through CORS?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, axios

I have a project that sends HTTP requests from the client using Axios

```
axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/`,
    withCredentials: true
  })
```

And I suppose this allows cookies -Which I am sure it shows in the browser before you ask- to be sent with the requests.

The problem occurs in the back-end, when this error shows in the log:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I tried this:

```
app.use(cors({
  //origin : to be set later
  credentials: true,
}))
```

and this instead:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

but neither seems to work.

### EDIT - Here is the answer for future visitors

With the help of the participants in comments, I found out I had to set the origin value:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin : "http://localhost:8080",
  credentials: true,
}))
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be a hostname not `*` when you send cookies.

Comment: please give more info about serverside code. ex.: `app.js` otherwise it seems like You're not using cookie parser

Comment: I added some info that may help.

Comment: What's the exact value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response?

Comment: we need  to see response headers from server. call: `curl -v -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8081` and put response to Your question

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` so, as I mentioned 20 minutes ago you must pass a hostname not the `*` there. And that's what the error message exactly tells you as well.

Comment: @zerkms YES, You are right, I had to change this to the hostname, as well as keeping the credentials options, and it works. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late for OP, but for those who keep comming here - what helped me is:

```
app.use(cors({
  preflightContinue: true,
  credentials: true,
}));
```

source: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem and I fixed it by setting the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` to the URL of my frontend instead of  "*"

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials